# StackOverflowError While Adding FormPage to FormEditor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have a really basic `FormEditor` and `FormPage`:

```
public class CustomFieldSetVersionEditor extends FormEditor {

    @Override
    protected void addPages() {
        try {
            addPage(new MyFormPage(this), getEditorInput());
        } catch (final PartInitException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void doSave(final IProgressMonitor monitor) {}

    @Override
    public void doSaveAs() {}

    @Override
    public boolean isSaveAsAllowed() { return false; }
}

class MyFormPage extends FormPage {

    public MyFormPage(final FormEditor editor) {
        super(editor, "id", "Title");
    }

    @Override
    protected void createFormContent(final IManagedForm managedForm) { }

}
```

This admittedly complex and exotic use case brings the following exception:

> java.lang.StackOverflowError
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.getData(Widget.java:525)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.getEditor(MultiPageEditorPart.java:599)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.getActiveEditor(MultiPageEditorPart.java:523)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.getActiveEditor(FormEditor.java:430)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor$FormEditorSelectionProvider.getSelection(FormEditor.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor$FormEditorSelectionProvider.getSelection(FormEditor.java:89)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor$FormEditorSelectionProvider.getSelection(FormEditor.java:89)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor$FormEditorSelectionProvider.getSelection(FormEditor.java:89)
>     ...

However, if I use `addPage(IFormPage)` instead of  `addPage(IEditorPart, IEditorInput)` it works. There is even a "bug" report for this problem: [Bug 283039](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=283039) (it's no bug, because... there is no reason given).

We don't need to discuss if this is a bug, but what I want to know is: How do I add a `FormPage` to a `FormEditor` while still defining the `IEditorInput`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FormPage` is being initialized twice, the second time with the same `IEditorSite` as the main `FormEditor`. This results in the same selection provider being used for the `FormPage` as the main editor, this selection provider does not expect this and gets in to a loop.

You can stop the second initialization by overriding the `isEditor` method of `FormPage` and return true:

```
@Override
public boolean isEditor() {
  return true;
}
```

Also note that if you use the `addPage(IFormPage)` call the page is still initialized with the editor input (as long as `isEditor` returns `false`).